# how to make progress bar line separate from checkpoints?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

[image]

Im trying to make that progress bar , but i finding some difficulty to separate line from checkpoints ,
here is what i tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  /* Style for the outer container */
  .outer-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh; /* 100% viewport height */
  }

  /* Style for the progress container */
  .progress-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
  }

  /* Style for the car icon */
  .car {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    transition: left 1s linear;
  }

  /* Style for the checkpoints */
  .checkpoint {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #88CCDF; /* Specify the color for the checkpoints */
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    margin-left: -5px; /* Adjusted to add space on both sides */
  }

  /* Style for the checkpoints in different states */
  .before-reached {
    background-color: #88CCDF; /* Default color for checkpoints before reaching */
  }

  .reached {
    background-color: yellow; /* Color for checkpoints when reached */
  }

  .passed {
    background-color: green; /* Color for checkpoints when passed */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <!-- Checkpoints -->
    <div class="checkpoint before-reached" style="left: 5%;"></div>
    <div class="checkpoint before-reached" style="left: 25%;"></div>
    <div class="checkpoint before-reached" style="left: 45%;"></div>
    <div class="checkpoint before-reached" style="left: 65%;"></div>
    <div class="checkpoint before-reached" style="left: 85%;"></div>
    
    <!-- Car icon -->
    <div class="car"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // JavaScript to move the car along the progress line
  const car = document.querySelector('.car');
  const checkpoints = document.querySelectorAll('.checkpoint');

  let currentCheckpointIndex = 0;

  function moveCarToNextCheckpoint() {
    if (currentCheckpointIndex < checkpoints.length - 1) {
      // Before reaching the next checkpoint, change the checkpoint color to yellow
      checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex].classList.remove('before-reached');
      checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex].classList.add('reached');

      currentCheckpointIndex++;
      const nextCheckpoint = checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex];
      car.style.left = nextCheckpoint.style.left;
    } else {
      // When the car passes all checkpoints, change the checkpoint color to green
      checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex].classList.remove('before-reached');
      checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex].classList.add('passed');
    }
  }

  // Initially, set the color of the first checkpoint to yellow (before reaching)
  checkpoints[currentCheckpointIndex].classList.add('before-reached');

  // Simulate progress by moving the car every 2 seconds
  setInterval(moveCarToNextCheckpoint, 2000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the result unfortunately is so far from the design :
[image]

I tried to put line div after each points didn't work , i tried to add margin to points and line didn't either .
Note : the js to make the red dot to move , it is like a "delivery tracking system" .

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves adding an extra element to your list.

What we basically want is the same circle you have but we want it to be white (or what ever the background color is) and slightly larger than the checkpoint.

To do this i have done the following

```
  .checkpoint {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #88CCDF; /* Specify the color for the checkpoints */
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left: -5px; /* Adjusted to add space on both sides */
  }
  .checkpoint-container{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
  }

    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 5%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
```

This should create a div that holds your checkpoint (the yellow dot). We can make this Div slightly larger than the yellow dot and make its background white. Then when its displayed it will provide a gap so to speak

```css
  /* Style for the outer container */
  .outer-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh; /* 100% viewport height */
  }

  /* Style for the progress container */
  .progress-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
  }

  /* Style for the checkpoints */
  .checkpoint {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #88CCDF; /* Specify the color for the checkpoints */
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left: -5px; /* Adjusted to add space on both sides */
  }
  .checkpoint-container{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150%;
  }

  .reached {
    background-color: yellow; /* Color for checkpoints when reached */
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <!-- Checkpoints -->
    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 5%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 25%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 45%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 65%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkpoint-container" style="left: 85%;">
        <div class="checkpoint before-reached"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ive removed the JS and the Car form  the snippet above but have shown how the containers work to make a space

Hope that helps!